# Regex for uuid hex value in django urls

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls, uuid

I am generating a uuid value and want to receive it from url in django, but the regex i am writing is not working and telling me page not found

```
import uuid
id = uuid.uuid4().hex
print id
be00e546822945bbb193b4ed80149c35
```

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9a-f]{32}\Z)/$', UserDetails.as_view(), name = 'users_detail'),
]
```

### Result:

```
"GET /users/be00e546822945bbb193b4ed80149c35/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3302
```

So what would be the correct regex for uuid hex value in urls.py ?

Comment: `\Z` means the very end of string. Try `^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9a-f]{32})/$` - see also https://regex101.com/r/7bIuWN/1

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *really* check that you have UUID, try this one:

```
[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12}
```

I've found it a while ago on SO and used it for a while to check that data is actually regexp. Haven't used it Django URLS directly, but I think it should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[^/]+)/$', UserDetails.as_view(), name = 'users_detail'),
]
```

Comment: Note that `[^/]+` will match any chars other than `/`, so, it will match `users/------/`, too.